# Roots with same size for polynomials with distinct degrees

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, polynomials, roots, common-root

I am working on a problem which just arrived at the following question related to roots of polynomials.

Let $f(x)=x^7-2x^6+1$ and $g(x)=x^{10}-2x^9+1$. These polynomials have $x=1$ as their unique common root (because $f(x)/(x-1)$ and $g(x)/(x-1)$ are irreducible).

However, I would like to proof the following: *If $\alpha\neq 1$ and $\beta\neq 1$ are roots of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, respectively, then $|\alpha|\neq |\beta|$.*

I would be very grateful for any suggestion.

Comment: By brute force, this would mean verifying that [this polynomial](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%28t%5E6+x%5E6%2Bt%5E5+x%5E5%2Bt%5E4+x%5E4%2Bt%5E3+x%5E3%2Bt%5E2+x%5E2%2Bt+x-1%2C+x%5E9%2Bx%5E8%2Bx%5E7%2Bx%5E6%2Bx%5E5%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E2%2Bx-1%2C+x%29+%3D+0) of degree $54$ has no roots on the unit circle.

Comment: @dxiv thanks for your suggestion. However, brute force is not very useful since I want to generalize this problem for higher degrees. I tried some inversion on circles etc, but always arrive at a very big polynomial for which we want information on size of roots.

Comment: You can work out resultants symbolically, too, though it's not necessarily pretty. As for the magnitude of roots, that's a well studied problem in relation to [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_polynomial) polynomials.